# PostgreSQL UPDATE with multiple SET

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I would like to update 2 columns in a table by replacing NULL values by 0.00. Say I have the following table content :

```
    ID        length_1        length_2
-------------------------------------------
     1           12.01            NULL
     2            NULL            6.02   
     3            NULL            NULL
```

Could I merge these two instructions inside a same one ? I would need to put both of them inside a rule after that :

```
UPDATE myTable SET length_1 = 0.00 WHERE length_1 IS NULL
UPDATE myTable SET length_2 = 0.00 WHERE length_2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE WHEN to put in the 0.00's else use length_1 if it has a value :

```
UPDATE myTable SET

length_1 = CASE 
           WHEN length_1 IS NULL 
           THEN 0.00 
           ELSE length_1
           END,

length_2 = CASE 
           WHEN length_2 IS NULL 
           THEN 0.00 
           ELSE length_2
           END ;
```

Comment: You may want to add `WHERE length_1 is null OR length_2 is null`. This will decrease execution time and table bloat.

Comment: Also `CASE WHEN length_1 IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE length_1 END` is equivalent to `COALESCE(length_1, 0.00)`

Answer (score 0):

Just test the value using `CASE WHEN` :

```
UPDATE myTable SET 
    length_1 = CASE WHEN length_1 IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE length_1 END,
    length_2 = CASE WHEN length_2 IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE length_2 END
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4cfa0/1).